# How to show commites, pushed only for some branch

Tags: git

I need to get list of commites, which pushed, for example, in 'task/105' branch.

I mean, i need get commites, pushed to 'task/105' branch, in range from first commit in 'task/105' branch, to the last.

I tried to do following:

```
git /dir/project
git checkout task/105
git log task/105
```

But it not help. It show to me commites for another branches and for 'test' branch both.

I readed, what i need to do something like this:

```
git log TASK_105_FIRST_COMMITE..task/105
```

But id dont know, how to get first commit for task/105
I readed, what it can help:

```
git merge-base master task/105
git log as65g76s5dgsd5gsd6sd65g4s...task/105
```

But i confused by the word 'master'. 
How if commit in master pushed after pushing commites in task/105?

Finally, i really don't know what to do...
Sorry for bad english

Comment: Do you need the list as an input into something else, or just to see the status of the repository?  Because if it's just to see the status, you could do `gitk --all` and see all the branches and their commits.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I need to see commites, which pushed for 'task/57' (example) branch.

Comment: A `git log master..task/57 --reverse` may be enough. `master..task/57` sets the start and end point for displaying the logs, and `--reverse` is self-explanatory.

Comment: ThibWeb, thx, your answer - it something what i need. Short and userful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm not sure what you mean by "first commit", and "pushed" makes me think you might be looking at a more restricted situation.)

In general, to mark particular commits with a name, one should use git's "tags", or a reference that "acts like" a tag.

Here's a bit of basic necessary background:

- Every commit in a git repository acts as a "snapshot" of a directory tree full of files.  This snapshot has an associated date, author/committer, and message.<sup>1</sup>
- Each commit also has a unique set of "parent commits" (none for a root commit, 1 parent for an ordinary commit, 2—or sometimes even more—for a merge commit).
- Each commit (and also the other three kinds of object stored in the repository) has a unique "true name", the SHA-1 ID, usually expressed as a 40-character hexadecimal string like `bd5d3781a8e32d3627bb1de70dc6b105dc9d77a0` (often shortened to the first 7 characters).
- These "true names" are unweildy and not good for human usage, so git adds "references" such as "branches" and "tags".  These are more user-friendly names like `refs/heads/master` and `refs/tags/v1.3`.  You can usually omit the `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` parts as well.

A branch or tag name is really just a way to specify the SHA-1, with one other exception:

- A "local" branch—a reference that lives in the `refs/heads/` namespace—is *automatically moved* when needed.  (A "remote" branch, in `refs/remotes/`, also moves when you `fetch` from the remote.  More generally the idea is that "branches move but tags don't".)

Adding a new commit, `git commit -m 'fix some bug'`, looks up the current branch—which could be `master`, or could be `task/105`, or any other valid branch-name string; it's a branch if it's prefixed by the usually-invisible `refs/heads/` part.  Having found the current branch (and its corresponding SHA-1 value), the `git commit` command writes a new commit into the repo, whose parent is the then-current SHA-1.  The new commit has a new unique SHA-1 value, and `git commit` then *changes* the branch name to point to the new commit, which people call "moving the branch forward".

Git does not<sup>2</sup> record the "old value" of the branch here.  It just changes the branch name -> SHA-1 mapping.  So how can you tell which commit the branch used-to point to?  The answer is that you *can't*, not with 100% reliability (see footnote 2).

If you need to mark a commit with a name, this is what "tags" are intended for.  There are two kinds of tags: "annotated" tags (which actually reside inside the git repository and can be authenticated if necessary), and "lightweight" tags.

A lightweight tag consists of an external name that lives in the `refs/tags/` namespace, pointing to a commit, just like a branch except that it does not move automatically.  (You can move it manually, with the "force" flags.)

An annotated tag consists of an external (lightweight) tag that points to a git repository object of type "tag", which carries information much like a git commit object: date, author, and so on.  However, a commit object "points to" a tree, while a tag object "points to" a commit object (which then points to a tree).<sup>3</sup>

With all that in mind, what people call "a branch" is usually a piece of a commit graph.  A commit graph is formed by taking all the externally-referenced commits (those with branch and tag names, plus a few other special cases) and "working backwards" along the parent references to find more commits.  This can be written or drawn something like this:

```
          o--o--o
         /       \
...--o--o--o--o---o--o   <-- refs/heads/master
         \
          o              <-- refs/tags/v0.9
           \
            o--o         <-- refs/heads/devel
```

Here the little `o`s depict commit nodes and the `<--` arrows show externally-referenced commits.

Thus, if you have a *single* repository (on your development machine, for instance) and want to know which commits happened "after point `X`" and "through the tip of branch pointed-to by name `Y`", you must save (somewhere) the "true name" (SHA-1) for "point `X`".  Let's say that "point `X`" was captured earlier when we made the tag `v0.9`, and that "point `Y`" is actually "branch `devel`".  Then:

```
v0.9..devel
```

is standard git revision-string shorthand that means "all commits reachable from the name `devel`, excluding all commits reachable from the name `v0.9`".  Since `v0.9` is a valid tag, this will get you just the bottom-most two `o--o` commits.

Asking for `master..devel` will get you "commits reachable from `devel`, excluding commits reachable from `master`".  It is not important that there are commits reachable from `master` that are not reachable from `devel`: you can think of this as taking a colored marker and drawing "backwards" from `refs/heads/master`, coloring in all the commits that can be reached by moving leftwards in the drawing (but never moving rightwards).  Then you take a second, different color and color in all the commits from `refs/heads/devel` but don't re-color any already-colored commits.  So in this case, `master..devel` gets you three commits: the one named by `refs/tags/v0.9`, plus the bottom two commits.

Now, you keep mentioning "pushed", which brings in a new and different wrinkle.  When you run `git push origin branch`, there are *two* repositories involved: yours, with your `refs/heads/branch` name, and "origin" (at some other URL), with *his* `refs/heads/branch` name.

If the push is successful at updating (and not "creating") his `refs/heads/branch`, that means he had some *previous* SHA-1 identified by `refs/heads/branch`, and once the push finishes, he has some new and different SHA-1 identified, specifically, the one you just pushed successfully.

If you want to know "what commit did his `refs/heads/branch` point to *before* I changed it", well, he's the only one who knows that.  The best way to find out is to ask him.  You can use `git ls-remote` to do this, or `git fetch`.  In general you should fetch before pushing anyway, so that's probably the appropriate option.  There is a problem here though, as there's a race between what he tells you when you ask (`ls-remote` or `fetch`) and what he has when you finally get around to `git push`-ing.  Even if you work really fast, in the few milliseconds between your query and your `push`, someone else could sneak in and do a different `push` and change things.  So the best way to find out what got updated "on his side" is to have him tell you, generally through a "post-receive hook".  (This hook gets handed "old-SHA-1, new-SHA-1, ref-name" triples.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In fact, there are two separate dates and user names, one for "author" and one for "committer".  Try `git cat-file -p HEAD` to see the (mostly-)raw data inside a commit.

<sup>2</sup>Actually, git *does* record the old value, in the "reflog" ... but reflogs are not permanent.  If you need to recover a forgotten SHA-1, within the expiration time, it's there; but if you want it as a more permanent item, that's not what the reflog is meant for, and it will be awkward to use it that way.

<sup>3</sup>In fact, tags can point to more (annotated) tags, and that's considered normal usage.  It's also physically possible to point any reference to a "tree" or "blob" inside the repository, but those are not normal uses for `refs/heads/` and `refs/tags/` references.